# How do I find out exact characters in a text input or file?

Tags: bash, terminal

I would like to find out which exact characters are in a text file. I have copied and pasted a bit of code from Stackoverflow and the seemingly perfect code caused a syntax error. When I wrote the exact same thing myself, it worked. Then I ran both snippets through `diff` and it showed that there is a difference, but the difference occurs in characters that both appear completely blank. I would really like to know what they are.

It isn't visible in the code block on Stackoverflow, but the number of spaces and tabs are also completely the same, at least from what both Sublime Text and `nano` interpret.

This is the output from when I compare the snippets with `diff`:

```
me@local /tmp $ cat a
$('.dropdown-layers').click(function(event){
        debug('here');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });​
me@local /tmp $ cat b
$('.dropdown-layers').click(function(event){
        debug('here');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
me@local /tmp $ diff a b
4c4
<   });​
---
>   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
diff a b | od -tx1
```

or some variant

Comment: i would to use `od -bc`. :) +1